# How to see a Google Cloud Function's network bandwidth statistics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Building my architecture using serverless functions, I am playing with Google Cloud Functions quite a bit and wanted to see the pricing structure. I save some stuff in MongoDB and post user notifications to Firestore so I do have content going out.

The pricing is based on:

- Number of invocations
- GB-seconds
- GHz-seconds
- Networking

The networking part is heavily influencing the final price, everything else is rather cheap. How can I look in the console how much bandwidth is one function using (a function as a whole, or even better, an execution of a function.)

Answer (score 1):

[Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) has some general metrics made readily available for purposes you mentioned. E.g. following:

- Executions
- Execution times
- Memory usage
- Network egress

Add a new dashboard to your Stackdriver Console and add some charts on it. While adding charts, enter `func` in the search field. You get a list of general metrics available for cloud functions. Choose metrics that you are interested in.